# Synchronous AMQP from PHP

Tags: php, messaging, rpc, amqp

Can PHP treat AMQP like an RPC service, and send a message and block until a reply is returned? Are there any good examples of this, and do any libraries wrap such functionality up in an easy-to-use way?

I'd like to have the flexibility of a brokered messaging system, but shield the web tier from needing to know about its asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, absolutely. Look at how an RPC-style request flows around a system:

1. A request is issued
2. The requester now blocks waiting for a reply to that request

That's completely implementable with an asynchronous message system like AMQP. You just need to do the RPC correlation yourself:

1. Send your request within an asynchronous message with a unique ID within it (this does not block)
2. Receive messages from the messaging system and block until you get a message back with the same unique ID (that means you've just received your reply)

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), an AMQP broker, offers [documentation online](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html) on how to do exactly this.

Comment: You may want to link to the [PHP version of the tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html) as the OP explicitly asked for PHP.