# Is RabbitMQ practical for RPC-esque bidirectional use during request processing?

Tags: rpc, rabbitmq

Super simple question, I couldn't find a concrete answer out there.

Is RabbitMQ suitable for RPC-like operations when processing HTTP requests?

I'm interested in firing off a message when a user HTTP request is received, waiting for the response from a backend server, and then sending the response to the client.

Is that a common use scenario? Are people doing it with success? Any pitfalls? Any examples or common design patterns?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381909/synchronous-amqp-from-php/9404566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we use rabbitmq in a similar fashion in production.

See [Request Reply Pattern](http://rubydoc.info/github/ruby-amqp/amqp/master/file/docs/PatternsAndUseCases.textile#Request_Reply_pattern)

Comment: Well I guess you can't argue with use in production! Thanks!

Comment: We looked all over for a simple way to expose amqp over http, its not a straight forward mapping. If was starting today I would do it with node.js (node-amqp) and build the http protocol the way i wanted to support my particular use cases. The biggest thing to think about is authentication via http to rabbit ..

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me, I do suggest you look at the Web messaging extentions/tools though:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#web-messaging